# Applying Transformation Matrixes to the Teapot Model

Tags: opengl, matrix, matrix-multiplication, coordinate-transformation

I'm new to openGL and right now I have a few functions that generate transformation matrixes, one of them being 4x4 and the other generating a 3x3 one. I've printed out the individual values in the matrixes and they're correct. Now I want to apply these values to the teapot model that comes built in to openGL. (The matrixes are filled with GLFloats).

Is there a way we can extract the matrix from the teapot and fill it in with the data from the new matrixes? If not, is there a way we can apply that values to the teapot easily?

EDIT:

here is the code I have so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

// standard
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

// glut
#include <GL/glut.h>

using namespace Eigen;
    using namespace std;

//================================
// global variables
//================================



// screen size
int g_screenWidth  = 0;
int g_screenHeight = 0;

// frame index
int g_frameIndex = 0;


int g_angle = 0;


void init( void ) {
    // init something before main loop...
}


void update( void ) {
    // do something before rendering...

    // rotation angle
    g_angle = ( g_angle + 5 ) % 360;




}

void quatMath(int w, int x, int y, int z)
{
    ArrayXXf transform(3,3);


      transform(0,0)= 1 -2*(y^2) - 2*(z^2);
      //calculating value for top left entry in matrix

      transform(0,1) = (2*x*y)  - (2*w*y);
    //calculating value for row 0 column 1

      transform(0,2) = (2*x*z) + (2*w*y);
          //row 0 column 2

      transform(1,0) = (2*x*y)+(2*w*z);
          //middle row, leftmost entry

      transform(1,1) = 1 - (2*(x^2)) - (2*(z^2));
          //middle row middle column

      transform (1,2) = (2*y*z) - (2*w*x);
          //middle row right column

      transform(2,0) = (2*x*z) - (2*w*y);
      //bottom row leftmost column

      transform (2,1) = (2*y*z) + (2*w*x);     
      //bottom row middle column

      transform(2,2) = 1 - (2*(x^2)) - (2*(y^2));   
      //bottom row right column

       std::cout << transform;
}

ArrayXXf fixedAngle(GLfloat initialX, GLfloat initialY, GLfloat initialZ, GLfloat rotX, GLfloat rotY, GLfloat rotZ)

{
      ArrayXXf z(4,4); //initializing the 4x4 rotation matrixes
      ArrayXXf y(4,4);
      ArrayXXf x(4,4);

      x<<1, 0, 0, 0,
          0, cos(rotX), -sin(rotX), 0,
          0, sin(rotX), cos(rotX), 0,
          0, 0, 0, 1;




      y<<cos(rotY), 0, sin(rotY), 0,
          0, 1, 0, 0,
          -sin(rotY), 0, cos(rotY), 0,
          0, 0, 0, 1;

      z<< cos(rotZ), -sin(rotZ), 0, 0,
          sin(rotZ), cos(rotZ), 0, 0,
          0, 0, 1, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 1;




      ArrayXXf fin(4,4);

      fin = x * y * z; 

      fin(0,3) = initialX;
      fin(1,3) = initialY;
      fin(2,3) = initialZ;
      //now we've moved the translational information into the final matrix
         std::cout << fin;
      return fin; 

}
//================================
// render
//================================
void render( void ) {
    // clear buffer
    glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClearDepth (1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 

    // render state
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    // enable lighting
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    // light source attributes
    GLfloat LightAmbient[]  = { 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat LightDiffuse[]  = { 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat LightSpecular[] = { 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat LightPosition[] = { 5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f, 1.0f };

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT , LightAmbient );
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE , LightDiffuse );
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, LightSpecular);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, LightPosition);

    // surface material attributes
    GLfloat material_Ka[]   = { 0.11f, 0.06f, 0.11f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat material_Kd[]   = { 0.43f, 0.47f, 0.54f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat material_Ks[]   = { 0.33f, 0.33f, 0.52f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat material_Ke[]   = { 0.1f , 0.0f , 0.1f , 1.0f };
    GLfloat material_Se     = 10;

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT   , material_Ka);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE   , material_Kd);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR  , material_Ks);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION  , material_Ke);
    glMaterialf (GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS , material_Se);

    // modelview matrix
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef (0.0, 0.0, -5.0);
    glRotated(g_angle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    // render objects
    glutSolidTeapot(1.0);

    // disable lighting
    glDisable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

    // swap back and front buffers
    glutSwapBuffers();
}



//================================
// timer : triggered every 16ms ( about 60 frames per second )
//================================
void timer( int value ) {   




    // increase frame index
    g_frameIndex++;

    update();

    // render
    glutPostRedisplay();

    // reset timer
    // 16 ms per frame ( about 60 frames per second )
    glutTimerFunc( 16, timer, 0 );
}

//================================
// main
//================================
int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    // create opengL window
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB |GLUT_DEPTH );
    glutInitWindowSize( 600, 600 ); 
    glutInitWindowPosition( 100, 100 );
    glutCreateWindow( argv[0] );


    fixedAngle(6, 4, 3, 5, 6, 3);

    cout<<"\n"; 

    quatMath(3, 4, 5, 6);

    // init
    init();

    // set callback functions
    glutDisplayFunc( render );
    glutReshapeFunc( reshape );
    glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );
    glutTimerFunc( 16, timer, 0 );

    // main loop
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean built in? How do you use it?

Comment: In openGL, you can render a teapot with a single glut command.

Comment: So glut has built in teapot, not OpenGL.

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.